# THREE JS PointLight smooth colour Interpolation animation effects like fastLED, WLED

Tags: javascript, colors, three.js, interpolation, fastled

You can find a Prototyp of [this Web Project here](https://pacala.blubber-lounge.de/) (this site is not up to date so the animate() function you will find there will probably not match the one below)

the color palette looks like this:

```
let party = [
    0x5500ab,
    0x84007c,
    0xb5004b,
    0xe5001b,
    0xe81700,
    0xb84700,
    0xab7700,
    0xabab00,
    0xab5500,
    0xdd2200,
    0xf2000e,
    0xc2003e,
    0x8f0071,
    0x5f00a1,
    0x2f00d0,
    0x0007f9
];
```

and i think to make it smoother we have to interpolate the colors

What i have so far in my THREE JS animation loop:

```
function animate(now) {
    // Convert to seconds
    now *= 0.001;
    // Subtract the previous time from the current time
    var deltaTime = now - then;
    // Remember the current time for the next frame.
    then = now;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
        const canvas = renderer.domElement;
        camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
      }

    if(now >= nextTime) {
        scene.children.forEach(function (e) {
            if (e.name.includes("pl")) {
                // track the current led index
                currentLed = currentLed >= numPixels-1 ? 0 : currentLed+1;
                // calculate the next index for the color palette
                currentColor = currentColor >= party.length-1 ? next=0 : Math.floor((next + currentLed)%(party.length-1));

                 // get new color from color palette "party"
                 var cc = new THREE.Color( party[currentColor] );

                // update PointLight light color
                e.color.setHex( cc.getHex() );
                 
                // update PointLight sphere color HELPER
                //e.children[0].material.color.setHex( color.getHex() );

            }
        });
        nextTime = now + .01;
    }

    if(now >= nextTime1) {        
        hue1 += 2;
        next += .1;
        nextTime1 = now + .01;
        
    }


    controls.update(); // auto rotate camera

    stats.update(); // display FPS thingy
    
    id = requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

i want this to transition smooth to the next color in the palette, just like [WLED](https://github.com/Aircoookie/WLED) is doing it.

> // update PointLight light color 
> e.color.setHex( cc.getHex() );

to be more exact... this value needs to be a interpolated value or something

> cc.getHex()

I tried to use the following effect (from WLED) as an inspiration....
[uint16_t WS2812FX::mode_palette() in FX.cpp 1659](https://github.com/Aircoookie/WLED/blob/392bda7d8cbaacae3d7e4cee7bd49f55ec90760a/wled00/FX.cpp#L1659)
but it did.. not.. work.. unfortunately... i worked my way down deep deep inside the wled code to figure out how this could possibly work.. but.... i have some what of not clue.

All i know is that the magic is somewhere around [at line 1056 in FX_fcn.cpp](https://github.com/Aircoookie/WLED/blob/392bda7d8cbaacae3d7e4cee7bd49f55ec90760a/wled00/FX_fcn.cpp#L1056) and [at line 1073 in FX_fcn.cpp](https://github.com/Aircoookie/WLED/blob/392bda7d8cbaacae3d7e4cee7bd49f55ec90760a/wled00/FX_fcn.cpp#L1073)
following this function to [line 552 in colorutils.cpp (FastLED GitHub Repo)](https://github.com/FastLED/FastLED/blob/b5874b588ade1d2639925e4e9719fa7d3c9d9e94/src/colorutils.cpp#L522) you can see the roots of all this... if i'm not mistaking then this method interpolats some colors probably... but i dont really know whats exactly going on.

i also tried to interpolate/ calculate the "next colors" with an [integrated method from THREE JS "lerp()"](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Color) but again not much luck either.

Comment: No, ofc not i want to set the pointLight color from a given palette with smooth transitions like a led strip has.

Comment: You could convert the hex values to HSL and use the `.setHSL()` method to achieve interpolations. A transition needs a start and end value which is provided in number based values like rgb, hsl etc, and not directly via hex values

Comment: something like [this right here](https://javascript.tutorialink.com/three-js-how-to-loop-lerp-through-more-than-two-colors-three-colors/) but for the pointlight color